# Mouse Events on JsFiddle not working?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I've got my fiddle here, but I can't understand why it's not calling my function on the 'onmouseout' event.
http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/Xf6LW/

any ideas?

Comment: Set your framework to: "nowrap (head)", and the script from the javascript pane will be appended to an empty script tag in the head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine, you just needed to put the function in the head (or body after the element is in the DOM) of the document.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Xf6LW/1/)**

Comment: Changed the first drop down menu to `no wrap (head)`. You could also select `no wrap (body)`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the functions you create in the JavaScript panel are not global when you have the onLoad option selected. Your JavaScript gets wrapped in a function.

If you do want them to be global you have to either do what j08961 suggested, by changing that dropdown to say no wrap (body or head) will work

The best solution would be to not set your event handlers from HTML, that's bad practice anyway, then you're not relying on global functions or mixing HTML and JS.

```
<div id="myDiv">
</div>​
document.getElementById('myDiv').onmousemove = function() {
  alert('here');
}
```

Side note: you should have noticed the error in the console saying that myFunc is undefined or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's cause for jsfiddle, it declares all the javascript AFTER the HTML. The HTML is going to run and look for a `myFunc` and not find it. Then it's going to load the JS and it won't even run it.

Comment: Not really, decalring the function after the HTML is not a problem. The problem is that jsfiddle wraps it with an anonymous function by default. Read mine and j08691's answers for a clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

make myFunc as a global function;

I searched my code using firebug and got following generated code.

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    //window.myFunc makes myFunc as a global function
    // It can be accessed from any were inside current window.
   window.myFunc = function myFunc(x)
   {
        alert('yo');
   }
    // function below is not available gloably.
    function myFunct1(){
        alert('yo1');
    }
});
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xf6LW/6/)

Comment: Works, but doesn't explain what the problem was.

Comment: if you search for window.myFunct, you will get following generated code window.addEvent('load', function() {
window.myFunc = function myFunc(x)
{
    alert('yo');
}
});//]]> which clearly reflect that scope of code you wrote is not global

Comment: you can get more information regarding JavaScript function scope from link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: Your explanation should be in your answer, I already understand function scope. What you don't understand is that you can change the behavior from the drop down.

Comment: If you're bored, go for a walk and don't be so annoying.

Comment: @DamianSIlvera annoying is fine, I prefer that than being careless

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the changes : [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Xf6LW/3/)

Comment: Cheap way of making it work without understanding what the problem was

Comment: the thing here was to make it works, it doesn't matter how. Works or not? :P

Comment: That's a naive way of coding and problem solving. Your solutions will always be brittle if you keep thinking that way. "Works or not?" makes you sound like you don't care about making it work properly.